# nested jobs in Quartz

Tags: java, timestamp, nested, quartz-scheduler

I have nested task to schedule:

(1). A daily master task downloading scheduling information, which is a List of job names with timestamps
(2). schedule the job in the scheduling information I just downloaded according to its timestamp

I am not sure how the nested jobs work in Quartz. It seems that I need a CronTrigger triggering a job, which contains multiple SimpleTriggered jobs. Are there any way to do that? Are there any alternatives?

Thanks.
Lily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't really nested jobs.

You are correct in that the master job needs a CronTrigger.  But when that job runs it will cycle through the list of jobs downloaded creating a job and a SimpleTrigger for each entry.  You can get a Scheduler from the CronJob's JobExecutionContext and add the jobs to it.

And bingo, all your jobs are scheduled.

Answer (score -1):

You basically need to run Quartz inside of your Quartz job.  This doesn't really make sense, why don't your just run all of the jobs with Quartz configurations?  I don't think this nesting is a good idea.

Comment: I am not quite get u... How can I do that?